# ESP32-CAM - A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)

Tags: microprocessors

I was trying to program my ESP32_CAM module, but every time I got this error:

```
Serial port COM4
Connecting.................................
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 30:c6:f7:51:82:d4
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Flash will be erased from 0x00001000 to 0x00005fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00008000 to 0x00008fff...
Flash will be erased from 0x0000e000 to 0x0000ffff...
Flash will be erased from 0x00010000 to 0x0016efff...
Compressed 18528 bytes to 12759...

A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)
A fatal error occurred: Packet content transfer stopped (received 8 bytes)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/89909) link says it means there is something wrong with the esp file system  rendering it "broken"... Not sure if there is a way to fix the issue though.

EDIT:
I found that if I disconnected some of my peripherals from esp32, the error went away. Perhaps too much power was being drawn.

Comment: I was flashing an ESP32 with MicroPython firmware with a connected display, it didn't work. I also had to do what you mentioned in the EDIT part (disconnect the display) to make it work.

Comment: +1. The same. I was trying to erase the flash using `esptools.py`. The thing was that my ESP was placed in a expansion board. After disconnect the problem went away and the flash was erased successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because I had the wrong 'partition scheme' selected under Arduino Tools.  There was nothing wrong with the ESP32.  I suggest trying other partition schemes.